# Django - filtering over many to many only checks first record

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many, django-queryset

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    model_b = models.ManyToManyField('models.ModelB')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    some_bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Given these two models, let's say I have two instances of ModelB related to an instance of ModelA...

```
mod_a = ModelA()
mod_a.save()

mod_b1 = ModelB(some_bool=True)
mod_b1.save()

mod_b2 = ModelB(some_bool=False)
mod_b2.save()

mod_a.model_b.add(mod_b1, mod_b2)
```

I now want to do a query similar to:

```
queryset = ModelA.objects.exclude(model_b__some_bool=True)
```

except that it iterates over ALL the related ModelB instances of a ModelA instance and excludes the instance if ANY of the ModelB instances' `some_bool` field is set to True. I'm aware this will require a more complex query (the one I have shown will only check the first instance of ModelB it comes across, and base entirely off that).

Comment: Make actual question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> the one I have shown will only check the first instance of ModelB it comes across, and base entirely off that

is not true. The query you have shown will do exactly what you want: exclude all ModelAs if *any* related model_b has some_bool=True.

Comment: OK, I'm clearly getting some unexpected behaviour somewhere then! Thanks.